# Transform image with PyTorch if image belongs to a certain class

Tags: python, pytorch

Is there a way to use PyTorch's transform functionality only if the image belongs to a specific class? Since some transformations on some classes lead to images that wouldn't be possible, I would like to do different augmentation on my training image based on the class that the image belong.

For example, say I had a classifier that differentiated between cats and dogs. If I only wanted to augment the images belonging to the cat class, how would I go about doing this with PyTorch?

Comment: Just to make sure, let's say you are working with classifying images of classes `dog` and `cat`. What you would like is to only transform images belonging to class `cat`, right ?

Comment: Yes it is possible.

Comment: @MaxD. - Yes, that is right. I updated the question to include this example.

Comment: What have you tried so far?